# Why is there not a parameterless implementation of TcpClient.Connect?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following:

```
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 0);
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient (ep);
tcpClient.Connect(ep);
```

Why must I tell the `tcpClient` to first bind to `ep` and the connect to `ep`. I seems strange compared to just `Connect()` to the already bound end point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx) that accepts an `IPEndpoint` is meant for binding a *local* endpoint address. [`Connect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6kc0793.aspx) is meant to be passed a *remote* endpoint address. One of these two things is in contradiction with the other.

constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the `TcpClient` class and binds it to the specified local endpoint.

`Connect`:

> Connects the client to a remote TCP host using the specified remote network endpoint.

But since we don't know whether `ep` is a local or remote endpoint, I can't tell you which one is wrong. I would guess at a local endpoint since you've specified `0`, in which case you need to identify a *different* endpoint for your `Connect` call - what are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Completely missed the "local" and "remote" adjectives!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something here, but there is a default constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329755(v=vs.71).aspx